# How to properly control data input?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, validation, input

There is a task to supervise input in . It is necessary to give the ability to enter only strings of numbers ([0-9]) into the entity input. At the same time, if something else is entered, then do not overwrite value and do not display incorrect input in the input. I can't find a solution for my case. Validity check ( target.validity.valid ) didn't work either because I have control over the minimum and maximum lengths. At the same time, I have a universal function for several inputs, but only the entity needs to be checked. Please tell me how to correctly implement the check for input [0-9] and so that nothing else can be entered.

The examples that are on the resource are not suitable because they do not take into account the control of the minimum-maximum length

Below is a shortened code example

```
const [inputState, setInputState] = useState({title : "", entity: ""})

  const handleChangeInputValue = (event) => {
    const { target } = event;
    const { name, value } = target;
    // Need to check for numbers
    setInputState({ ...inputState, [name]: value });
  };


              <input
                required
                minLength={5}
                type="text"
                placeholder="Enter name"
                name="title"
                value={inputState.title}
                onChange={handleChangeInputValue}
              />
              <input
                required
                minLength={13}
                maxLength={15}
              
                type="text"
                placeholder="Enter entity"
                name="entity"
                value={inputState.entity}
                onChange={handleChangeInputValue}
              />
```

Comment: Do any of [these](https://www.techiedelight.com/restrict-html-input-text-box-to-allow-only-numeric-values/) help?

Comment: no, unfortunately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(name==='entity' && !value.match(/^\d+$/)) { 
return
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use HTML 5

```
<input type="number" name="someid" />
```

This will work only in HTML5 complaint browser. Make sure your html document's doctype is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Comment: One complaint: make that browser *compliant*.